# What would cause IE9 to not interpret, or disregard parts of a web page?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

It appears that IE (v9 in this instance) simply does not see or chooses to not interpret sections of the HTML code in a web page.  I have two examples which I will refer to here -

1)  In this page, http://www.tigerswrestling.net/lshs/seasons/current_season/index.php?program=lshs, IE9 fails to process the entire page, save for the ".article" div.  FF and Chrome successfully parse the entire page correctly.

2)  In this page, http://www.tigerswrestling.net/index.php, IE9 does not parse the "page-wrap" div - until AFTER the user has clicked on the page somewhere.  Again, FF and Chrome do not have trouble interpreting or displaying this page.

This has really got me stumped.  I'll appreciate any input from the experts here.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works the same in all browsers for me. But when I turn on Compatability view mode in Ie9, it breaks. Turn that off.

Comment: Step 1 of any non-rendering problem:  Fix your markup.  Any reason why you are using **transitional** instead of strict?  With XHTML being dead,  you should either switch to HTML 4.01 strict or HTML 5.  http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tigerswrestling.net%2Flshs%2Fseasons%2Fcurrent_season%2Findex.php%3Fprogram%3Dlshs&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Regarding #1, validating absoutely wwas the resolution.  there were several markup errosr that I repaired and it is being displayed correctly in all browsers.

Comment: However, as for #2 [link](http://www.tigerswrestling.net/index.php).   Fixing all markup errors and warnings HAS NOT helped.  IE stsill will not display/render the "page_wrap" div unril/unless the user clicks somewhere on the page.  Any ideas about this issue?

Comment: Validating the markup IS the answer to fix the problem. Thanks Jukka. Should have started there,

Comment: However, as for #2 [link](http://www.tigerswrestling.net/index.php), fixing all markup errors and warnings HAS NOT helped. IE stsill will not display/render the "page_wrap" div unril/unless the user clicks somewhere on the page. Any ideas about this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The [validation report](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://www.tigerswrestling.net/lshs/seasons/current_season/index.php?program=lshs) for the first page contains rather serious-looking syntax errors, like attempts to nest comments. Such errors may well confuse some browsers, and there’s really no specification on what is the right thing to do with syntactically malformed documents.

So validating the markup should at least be the first step in trying to fix the problem.

Comment: Validating the markup IS the answer to fix the problem.  Thanks Jukka.  Should have started there,

Comment: However, as for #2 [link](http://www.tigerswrestling.net/index.php), fixing all markup errors and warnings HAS NOT helped. IE stsill will not display/render the "page_wrap" div unril/unless the user clicks somewhere on the page. Any ideas about this issue?

Comment: @Mark, page #2 looks OK on my IE 9 (Win 7). If I change it to Quirks Mode, then the problem appears: only the background images is seen. But in inspection mode (F12), I can see that IE has parsed the document OK and the `span class=button` elements (when clicked on in the “HTML” pane) get blue borders, though they seem to have no content and to be oddly placed. Turning off CSS makes the content appear. So it’s apparently something in the style sheet.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm really not sure what I did, but it seems that IE9 is working now!  I really only develop in and for FF and Chrome, which, I know is not ideal, but my audience is captive!  :)  Next step for me is to makethis site to be responsive for the mobile devices that are  used to see it.  Thanks again.